# Python and GeoTiff images, scrolling problem

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a problem, this is the code that opens the GeoTiff mini photo gallery window but the scrolling does not work for me. What is wrong in the code? I have the impression that the rewind and the photos are two separate things, I don't know how to "glue" them together. Thank you very much for your help.

```
import tkinter as tk
import glob


from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import rasterio as rio

from rasterio.plot import show

SIZE_X = 100

SIZE_Y = 100

class Icon:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    self.ybar = tk.Scrollbar(self.root)
    self.item_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=354, height=401,
                                 yscrollcommand=self.ybar.set)

    self.ybar.configure(command=self.item_canvas.yview)

    self.item_canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000))
    self.item_canvas.configure(background='#d8d8d9')

    self.ybar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    self.item_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE, fill=tk.BOTH)

    self.get_icons()

def get_dir(self):
    link = r'work_dir/*.txt'
    with open(link) as f:
        self.file_photo = f.read()
        self.link_to_dir = glob.glob(self.file_photo.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/*.tif')
        self.number = len(self.link_to_dir)

def get_icons(self):
    '''Method to add a mini gallery'''
    self.get_dir()

    FIGSIZE = 2.5
    self.counter = -1

    if self.number <= 2:
        for i in range(0, self.number):
            self.fig = Figure(figsize=(FIGSIZE, FIGSIZE), dpi=60)
            self.canvasGeo = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.root)
            self.canvasGeo.get_tk_widget().place(x=i * 220, y=10)

            with rio.open(self.link_to_dir[i]) as src_plot:
                show(src_plot, ax=self.fig.add_subplot())
            self.canvasGeo.draw()


    elif self.number > 2:
        k = int()
        y = []
        for i in range(0, self.number):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                k = i
            y.append(k)
        for j in range(0, self.number):
            self.counter += 1
            if (j * 220) <= 220:
                self.fig = Figure(figsize=(FIGSIZE, FIGSIZE), dpi=60)
                self.canvasGeo = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.root)
                self.canvasGeo.get_tk_widget().place(x=10 + j * 190, y=10)

                with rio.open(self.link_to_dir[y[j]]) as src_plot:
                    show(src_plot, ax=self.fig.add_subplot())
                self.canvasGeo.draw()
            else:
                self.fig = Figure(figsize=(FIGSIZE, FIGSIZE), dpi=60)
                self.canvasGeo = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.root)
                self.canvasGeo.get_tk_widget().place(x=(-175 * y[j]) + j * 180, y=85*y[j])

                with rio.open(self.link_to_dir[y[j]]) as src_plot:
                    show(src_plot, ax=self.fig.add_subplot())
                self.canvasGeo.draw()
    else:
        tk.Label(self.root, text='Wrong Value').place(x=220, y=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Icon(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

New code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Icon(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.select_images_button = Button(self)
        self.select_images_button["text"] = "Select Images"
        self.select_images_button["command"] = self.select_images
        self.select_images_button.pack()

        self.quit = Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack()

        self.images_label = Label(self)
        self.images_label.pack()

        self.scale = Scale(self, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                           command=self.resize_image)
        self.scale.set(100)
        self.scale.pack()

    def select_images(self):
        self.files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file",
                                           filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
        self.load_image()

    def load_image(self):
        self.image = Image.open(self.files[0])
        self.resized_image = self.image.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_image)
        self.images_label.configure(image=self.photo)
        self.images_label.image = self.photo

    def resize_image(self, value):
        size = int(value)
        self.resized_image = self.image.resize((size, size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_image)
        self.images_label.configure(image=self.photo)
        self.images_label.image = self.photo

root = Tk()
app = Icon(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I don't see the differences in the code, but I replaced those lines unfortunately it still doesn't work. The size of the widget has changed, the slider does not scroll the images.

Comment: Add the following line after self.item_canvas.pack :
`self.item_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.fig, anchor='nw')`

Comment: Can you point to the location again? because in the code regardless of the location I have an error on windows=self.fig, it does not accept it.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Icon' object has no attribute 'fig'

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code, check the answer again and copy/paste the full code and tell me if anything works or not!